# Processing interface annotations by maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have an `annotation-processor` java app that is looking into the `target` folder of the external maven project for the class files. This app uses `URLClassLoader`. The target folder is the absolute path app parameter. I have a simple junit test which is loading classes and processing the annotations successfully. Now I wrote the maven plugin that is just a wrapper for `annotation-processor` app. When running this maven plugin, `annotation-processor` loads the classes but it does not see any annotations in those. How can I access class/interface annotations from the maven plugin?

- maven-plugin-plugin:3.6.4
- java 11.0.15

```
    private static Class<?> getClass(String path, String className, String packageName) {
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        return cl.loadClass(packageName + "." + className));
        } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.warn("Cannot find class: " + packageName + "." + className, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Example call:

```
Class clazz = getClass("/home/user/java/my-project/target/classes", "MyClass", "com.my.example.package");
assert clazz.getAnnotations() > 0;
```

Comment: is the retention policy of the annotation RUNTIME?

Comment: Yes, all the annotations do have Runtime RP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. your annotations do not have proper `@Retention`
2. JVM silently drops information about annotations while loading the class - that may happen if classloader does know nothing about annotation classes - that is very likely your case because you are instantiating new classloader without specifying parent

Comment: No matter what `Retention` is used, the annotation is not visible in the plugin. However it is visible in the simple junit test using the very same logic as plugin :(

Comment: @stanly what about the second reason?

Comment: You are right! I passed class loader from the plugin to the `annotation-processor` and the annotations are loaded correctly! Thank you so much!